# Program not executing fine- Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I downloaded Selenium 2.53 version, now I have Selenium 3.2 version, both times same blank page opened, no URL . pls chk below error message.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class AadminLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("WebDriver.gecko.driver","C:/geckoDriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("Kawal");`
    }
}
```

> Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '8c03df6', time: '2017-03-02 09:30:17 -0800'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-BTAFHIV', ip: '192.168.153.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:293)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:272)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:267)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:263)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:122)
>       at abcd.AadminLogin.main(AadminLogin.java:12)

Comment: What are the versions of the geckodriver and Firefox that are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change :

```
System.setProperty("WebDriver.gecko.driver","C:/geckoDriver.exe");
```

To :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/geckodriver.exe");
```

> In Selenium 3.x the Key-Value pair is expressed as **`webdriver.gecko.driver`** and **`C:/geckoDriver.exe`**

Answer (score 0):

Try with updating code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class AadminLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/geckodriver.exe"); //Here changes are made
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("Kawal");`
    }
}
```

All other things are fine. it is just some casing issue in `setProperty()`. And for 2.53 there is no need of geckodriver